# How to get remote access to a MySQL database on my computer?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've read around a lot and tried all the suggestions but nothing seems to be working.

I want my java program to be able to remotely access a database on my computer. I tried using an IP address for the host name but that doesn't work. The only thing that allows the program to connect to the database is using localhost as the host name.

Would it work to use localhost for the host name? (jdbc url - jdbc:mysql://hostname/dbname)

Comment: Off course it will work by replacing with localhost but you should also provide port number which is assigned to your mysql database e.g. `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase`

Comment: "nothing seems to be working" doesn't really tell us anything at all about what is going on.   Specifics, please?  Error messages?   Something?  `localhost` always means *this computer*.  It never means a different computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Java program is running on a different computer to the one MySQL is running on, you may need to set user privileges in MySQL to allow remote connections to it.

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors that you need to take into account. When you say remote and mean outside of your (WiFi) network you need to setup a static IP or a DDNS service so you can route anyone to the computer that hosts the database. Second, you need to make sure your database has remote access privileges as mentioned. It is only after both of these conditions are met that you'll be able to access the database 'remotely'.

To grant all computers privileges to your database you can use the SQL command: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;` or if you want to be more specific as to what IP addresses you want to access the database: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'[IP Address Here]' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`.

Be sure to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after making changes.